# Missing definition from ACCESS_MASK

Tags: windows, msdn

The documentation for ACCESS_MASK ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) defines bits 16-23 as following :

`16–23    Standard rights. Contains the object's standard access rights.`

but the standard rights table only describes bits 16-20. where are the 3 missing bits ?

they are not decribed in any other sections. in fact setting all the masks defined in headers makes the flags missing those 3 bits. (and the reserved bits).

```
Bit   Flag          Meaning
---------------------------------------
16  DELETE          Delete access.
17  READ_CONTROL    Read access to the owner, group, and discretionary access control list (DACL) of the security descriptor.
18  WRITE_DAC       Write access to the DACL.
19  WRITE_OWNER     Write access to owner.
20  SYNCHRONIZE     Synchronize access.
```

Are those bits used anywhere ? Even internally to the system (not exposed by userspace functions)

Or are they also reserved ?

From what I see it might be just a way to pad the "section" of flags of std rights to 8 bits. If thats the case they could at least mention it somwhere ? Then again it might be a secret NSA backdoor !

I need this info because im writing a Virtual Filesystem that hooks all file functions so i need to understand them fully.

Comment: right. downvote without a reason is best idea there is.

Comment: IIRC, the Windows file system API has functions that will take care of checking permissions for you, so you don't really need to know.  But most likely those bits are simply unused (so far).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now i noticed they possibly are relicts of the following flags

```
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ             (READ_CONTROL)
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE            (READ_CONTROL)
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE          (READ_CONTROL)
```

that now were integrated with the READ_CONTROL flag. mystery solved.

Comment: Those constants specify the standard rights that are required for the respective operations. All 3 require reading the object owner/DACL. So I don't think this answer is right. The standard rights have been bits 16-23, with 21-23 unassigned, since the initial release of Windows NT over 20 years ago. I don't think there's a mystery to be solved (but I'm not the downvoter).